# How to add case statement with calculations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I tried a case statement from SAP Business One database to get the downpayment amount without tax by considering the tax type. But it returned following error.

> 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'

Here my code for reference

```
select (case when taxcode = 'NBT2' then (cast(LineTotal as decimal(22,8)) /1.02) else '' end) from DPI1
```

this worked without case like as follows,

```
select (cast(LineTotal as decimal(22,8)) /1.02)  from DPI1
```

what was the error. How can i overcome this?

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. `Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in T-SQL.

Comment: What happens, when you replace the empty string (`''`) in the `ELSE` branch with `NULL`?

Comment: @stickybit this was the error. I should be corrected as LineTotal instead of ''

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `CASE` expression, both output of case should return same datatype otherwise it will end up with `CAST` error.

As @Larnu said, Implicit coversion will happen only for `Int` / `Float` not for `Decimal`, so when you are returning decimal in case expression then you need to cast explicitly otherwise return 0 or null.

> In your case, `CAST(LineTotal AS decimal(22,8)) /1.02` return `NULL`
>   and else returns empty string, which causing the error

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN taxcode = 'NBT2' THEN (CAST(LineTotal AS decimal(22,8)) /1.02) 
             ELSE 0.0 END) 
FROM DPI1
```

Or

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN taxcode = 'NBT2' THEN (cast(LineTotal AS decimal(22,8)) /1.02) 
             ELSE NULL END) 
FROM DPI1
```

Comment: No @Larnu. It should be the error, Please check your query here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1ad7b2dc2b62f7a2fe76515370e07290

Comment: Obviously the coffee hasn't set in yet. `''` can be implicitly converted to an `int` and brain just said "numerical" data types.

Comment: @Larnu In `SQL Server` ''  string wont cast implicitly to numerical data type and we may explicitly convert it to as `CAST('' AS INT)`... Will you agree my answer?

Comment: No, that isn't true, @Neverdie `decimal`/`Numeric`, `float`/`real` and `int` all behave quite differently. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5f5194aa620f37f3c2809b7a2b1f65de). Notice only `decimal` fails, not `float` and `int`.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I agree this but user wants output in `Decimal`.

Comment: Yes, but you said in your latter comment *"`''` string wont cast implicitly to numerical data type"* which isn't true. It won't cast to a `numeric`/`decimal`, but it will cast to other numerical data types.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when taxcode = 'NBT2' then (cast(LineTotal as decimal(22,8)) /1.02) else null end) from DPI1
```

use above Query